# Keras Always Output a Constant Value

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I've been training a simple Artificial Neural Network using Keras

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_shape=(32,), activation = 'relu'),
    Dense(20, activation='relu'),
    Dense(65, input_shape=(65,), activation='softmax')
])

model.summary()
model.compile(Adam(lr=.001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_samples, train_labels, batch_size=1000, epochs=10000,shuffle = True, verbose=2)
```

After training, I test the model, and it always outputs a constant value. What shall I do?

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1727

The link above tells that I have to center my data to have a zero mean. I don't have any idea to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to center your data to have zero mean, just subtract sample mean from each samples.

e.g if you have `features` data and want to center it to have zero mean, you can do that using [numpy's mean function](http://lagrange.univ-lyon1.fr/docs/numpy/1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) as follows.

```
features = features - np.mean(features)
```

You may also need to normalize using standard deviation. This can be achieved by using numpy as follows.

```
normalized_features = (features - np.mean(features))/ np.std(features)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `'relu'` activations without caring for it going to all zeros.

Relu has a "zero region" when its input is negative, and this region, naturally has no gradient, so there is no possibility of it changing over training.

If all neurons in a layer go to the zero region, your model is frozen forever.

One thing you can do is to replace `'relu'` by `'sigmoid'` or `'tanh'`.
Another thing is to use a `BatchNormalization` layer before it.

The `BatchNormalization` does the centering for you, besides adding some speed to training and a little regularization.

```
model = Sequential([

    #optional BatchNormalization(input_shape(32,))

    Dense(32, input_shape=(32,)),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu')
    Dense(20),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    Dense(65, input_shape=(65,), activation='softmax')
])
```